# Extract all text between two delimiters when both delimiters appear multiple times in a string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several rows of chat data that contain transcripts which look like this:

> "Participant 1 (Me): I don't know the answer to this. Participant 2:
>   What do you think?   Maybe 20%? Participant 2: I don't know either.
>   Participant 1 (Me): that was my guess Participant 2: ok, let's go for
>   it! ...what do you think? Participant 1 (Me): sure! Participant 2: ok!
>   Participant 2: aww! sorry!"

I would like to extract only the text that follows the prefix `Participant 1 (Me):` up until it says either `Participant 1` or `Participant 2`.  All the text that follows immediately after `Participant 1` up until the aforementioned delimiters should be stored in variable called `participant_1_text`.  I'd like to store all the remaining text in a separate variable called `participant_2_text`, like so:

```
participant_1_text = "I don't know the answer to this. that was my guess. sure!
participant_2_text = "What do you think?   Maybe 20%? I don't know either. ok, let's go for
it! ...what do you think? ok! aww! sorry!"
```

So all of Participant 1's text and all of Participant 2's texts are now separated.

I tried something like the following regex:

```
(?<=Participant 1)(.*)(?=Participant 2)
```

But that will match all text between the first and last occurrence of those two delimiters, instead of every match.

---

Edit: I'm trying to now take below versions of code and apply them to a dataframe containing lots of chat transcripts:

So, taking @akrun's code I made a function that separates out a given chat log to `my_chat` or `partner_chat` and returns a named list:

```
extract_chat <- function(chat_text){
  final_output = chat_text %>% 
    tibble(col1 = chat_text) %>% 
    mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, "Participant", "\nParticipant")) %>% 
    separate_rows(col1, sep="\n") %>% 
    filter(nzchar(col1)) %>% #filter the non-empty strings
    separate(col1, into = c('Participant', "text"), sep=":") %>% 
    group_by(Participant) %>% 
    summarise(text = str_c(text, collapse= ' ')) %>% 
    mutate(Participant = ifelse(str_detect(Participant, "(Me)"), "my_chat_extracted", "partner_chat_extracted")) %>%
    spread(Participant, text)   

  return(list(my_chat_extracted = final_output$my_chat_extracted,
              partner_chat_extracted = final_output$partner_chat_extracted))
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm not sure how to mutate the actual columns in my data-frame to use this function.

Here's an example of a data.frame to use:

```
str1 <- "Participant 1 (Me): I don't know the answer to this. Participant 2: What do you think? Maybe 20%? Participant 2: I don't know either. Participant 1 (Me): that was my guess Participant 2: ok, let's go for it! ...what do you think? Participant 1 (Me): sure! Participant 2: ok! Participant 2: aww! sorry!"
str2 <- "Participant 1 (Me): Hey, how are you? Participant 2: I'm good, how about you? Participant 2: I'm excited.  Participant 1 (Me): I'm also good."
test = data.frame(chat = c(str1, str2))
```

I want to do something like:

```
   tester = test %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(my_chat_extracted = extract_chat(chat)$my_chat_extracted)
```

But this seems to be pretty slow on my actual dataset, and feels sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can insert a next line character before the `Participant` (with `str_replace_all`), then split at the `\n` with `separate_rows`, `filter` out any blanks (`nzchar`), `separate` the column into two at `:`, grouped by 'Participant', `paste` the 'text' strings into a single string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
out <- tibble(col1 = str1) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, "Participant", "\nParticipant")) %>% 
  separate_rows(col1, sep="\n") %>% 
  filter(nzchar(col1)) %>%
  separate(col1, into = c('Participant', "text"), sep=":") %>% 
  group_by(Participant = str_remove(Participant, "\\s*\\(.*")) %>% 
  summarise(text = str_c(text, collapse= ' '))

out
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Participant   text                                                                                                                    
#  <chr>         <chr>                                                                                                                   
#1 Participant 1 " I don't know the answer to this.   that was my guess   sure! "                                                        
#2 Participant 2 " What do you think? Maybe 20%?   I don't know either.   ok, let's go for it! ...what do you think?   ok!   aww! sorry!"
```

It may be better to keep it in a `data.frame`, but if we need separate objects use `list2env` after `deframe`ing

```
library(tibble)
list2env(as.list(deframe(out)), .GlobalEnv)
`Participant 1`
#[1] " I don't know the answer to this.   that was my guess   sure! "
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Participant 1 (Me): I don't know the answer to this. Participant 2: What do you think? Maybe 20%? Participant 2: I don't know either. Participant 1 (Me): that was my guess Participant 2: ok, let's go for it! ...what do you think? Participant 1 (Me): sure! Participant 2: ok! Participant 2: aww! sorry!"
```

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant.  What is the `group_by(Participant = str_remove(Participant, "\\s*\\(.*")) %>% ` line doing?

Comment: @Parseltongue. It is just that some strings have the `(me)` .  It is to remove that, so that we can have Particiapant 1, 2, without that suffix

Comment: I've been trying to modify the code to work with a pre-existing data-frame (I have a column of those chats, and want to separate them out to `my_chat` and `partner_chat` based on whether it says (me) or not. Could you take a look at my edited code above and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Would really appreciate it!

Comment: @Parseltongue Not clear about the expected `test %>% rename(col1 = chat) %>%mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, "Participant", "\nParticipant")) %>%` seems to be working

Comment: Sorry -- did you see my edit?  I'm trying to use the logic of your code, but applied to an entire data.frame column of chat transcripts.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do so.

Comment: @Parseltongue if it is slow, then can you use `map` i.e. `library(purrr);test %>% mutate(my_chat_extracted = map_chr(chat, ~extract_chat(.x)$my_chat_extracted))`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this using `stringr`, where `s` is the given string:

```
r <- "Participant \\d( \\(Me\\))?: "
cbind(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(s, r)), strsplit(s, r)[[1]][-1])
#>      [,1]                   [,2]                                         
#> [1,] "Participant 1 (Me): " "I don't know the answer to this. "          
#> [2,] "Participant 2: "      "What do you think? Maybe 20%? "             
#> [3,] "Participant 2: "      "I don't know either. "                      
#> [4,] "Participant 1 (Me): " "that was my guess "                         
#> [5,] "Participant 2: "      "ok, let's go for it! ...what do you think? "
#> [6,] "Participant 1 (Me): " "sure! "                                     
#> [7,] "Participant 2: "      "ok! "                                       
#> [8,] "Participant 2: "      "aww! sorry!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method using stringr:

```r
library(stringr)  

txt <- "Participant 1 (Me): I don't know the answer to this. Participant 2: What do you think? Maybe 20%? Participant 2: I don't know either. Participant 1 (Me): that was my guess Participant 2: ok, let's go for it! ...what do you think? Participant 1 (Me): sure! Participant 2: ok! Participant 2: aww! sorry!"

txt %>%
  str_split("(?=Participant.+:)", simplify = TRUE)  %>%
  str_split(": ", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  .[-1, ]

#>      [,1]                 [,2]                                         
#> [1,] "Participant 1 (Me)" "I don't know the answer to this. "          
#> [2,] "Participant 2"      "What do you think? Maybe 20%? "             
#> [3,] "Participant 2"      "I don't know either. "                      
#> [4,] "Participant 1 (Me)" "that was my guess "                         
#> [5,] "Participant 2"      "ok, let's go for it! ...what do you think? "
#> [6,] "Participant 1 (Me)" "sure! "                                     
#> [7,] "Participant 2"      "ok! "                                       
#> [8,] "Participant 2"      "aww! sorry!"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>